# How to use the Google satellite view as tile in leaflet with R

Tags: r, google-maps, leaflet, ggmap, satellite-image

Many questions seem similar to mine, I could not however find a fitting answer for R.

So far, I use the awesome R leaflet (and ggmap) package that way:

```
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)

coord <-geocode('New York')

map.city <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/transport/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=68c4cd328d3b484091812a76fae093fd') %>%
setView(coord$lon, coord$lat, zoom = 11)
```

But what if I want as a map the Google satellite?

I went through this post

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394190/leaflet-map-api-with-google-satellite-layer#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394190/leaflet-map-api-with-google-satellite-layer#_=_)

but don't understand how to use the googleSat function defined there.

Comment: If it has to be google satellite imagery you could try the [googleway](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/index.html) package. If other satellite imagery is ok, you can use "Esri.WorlImagery" in **leaflet**: ```map.city <- leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldImagery') %>%
    setView(coord$lon, coord$lat, zoom = 11)```

Comment: Thanks, that can already do the job. The Esri.WorlImagery however does not give the details of the buildings and of the roads. Googleway seems to be an interesting alternative, even though I could not find an equivalent to the controler of leaflet (i.e. how to switch on/off groups)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "details of the buildings and the roads". if you refer to the google hybrid map with street names then you could add "CartoDB.PositronOnlyLabels" to at leaste get streest and place names. ```map.city <- leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldImagery') %>% setView(coord$lon, coord$lat, zoom = 11);
map.city %>% addProviderTiles("CartoDB.PositronOnlyLabels")```

Comment: @XavierPrudent - (googleway author here) no, you can't control groups on the map directly yet, but it's in the pipeline

Comment: Well, given the current status of these packages, I would say TimSalabim and SymbolixAU feel free to turn your comment into an answer, as these are what I am going to use. (btw, impressive package that googleway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the actual Google Maps (which comes with satellite view) you can use my `googleway` package

```
library(googleway)

apiKey <- 'your_api_key'
mapKey <- 'your_map_key'

newYork <- google_geocode(address = "New York", key = apiKey)

google_map(location = as.numeric(newYork$results$geometry$location), 
           key = mapKey)
```

[image]

The [vignette](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/blob/master/vignettes/googleway-vignette.Rmd) has more examples of what you can do with the maps.

Answer (score 19):

If it has to be google satellite imagery you could use the [googleway](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/index.html) package. If other satellite imagery is ok, you can use "Esri.WorlImagery" with or without "CartoDB.PositronOnlyLabels" in leaflet:

```
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)

coord <-geocode('New York')

map.city <- leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldImagery') %>% 
  setView(coord$lon, coord$lat, zoom = 11)
map.city %>% addProviderTiles("CartoDB.PositronOnlyLabels")
```